# Use "run keyword if" to call a function with a string argument, but without altering the string

Tags: robotframework

I ran into an odd issue so I wrote this example where I call "print ${dir}" twice:

```
*** Variables ***
${dir} =  "c:\\temp"

*** Test Cases ***   
Test
    print ${dir}
    run keyword if    1 == 1    print ${dir}

*** Keywords ***  
print ${input1}
    log to console    \r${input1}
```

Output:

```
"c:\temp"
"c:     emp"
```

What do I need to do to make "print ${dir}" print the same thing each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact you're using the embedded argument syntax. In order for robot to know what keyword to call, it must first do expansion of the variable *before*  calling the keyword. That removes one layer of backslashes. Then, when your keyword passes what's left to the `log to console` keyword it sees `\t` as a tab character, which is why you see a tab character rather than the backslash and the letter "t".

One solution is to use traditional arguments rather than embedded arguments. The following example gives the same output for both times the keyword is called:

```
*** Variables ***
${dir} =  "c:\\temp"

*** Test Cases ***   
Test
    print  ${dir}
    run keyword if    1 == 1    print  ${dir}

*** Keywords ***  
print
    [Arguments]  ${input1}
    log to console    \r${input1}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the `Run Keyword If` keyword does some additional escaping of the backslashes. By adding 1 more backslash you'll see it happen in the first example as well.

To overcome this issue is to switch from backslashes () to forward slashes (/). This works on both *nix and Windows based systems.

```
 *** Variables ***
 ${dir} =  "c:\\temp"
```

to

```
 *** Variables ***
 ${dir} =  "c:/temp"
```

This still makes a valid path on Windows. So functionally the path reference will work as well.